# Laravel redirect to primary domain

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-301

I have an app built with Laravel where clients can have a primary domain and any number of other domains.

If a user visits the app on a domain other than the primary domain, I would like to 301 redirect them to the same page on the primary domain.

I have the following code in my the boot method of my AppServiceProvider but I don't think this is using a 301 redirect - I don't want clients to be penalised for duplicate content.

```
$domain = \App\Domain::where('name', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])->firstOrFail();
if(!$domain->primary)
{
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https' : 'http';
    redirect($protocol.'://'.$domain->client->primaryDomain->name.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])->send();
}
```

Is there a better alternative to this?

Comment: `redirect($url, 301);` should do the job.

Comment: That'll do it... just needed to be `redirect($url, 301)->send();`